# How can you test values passed to EJS file rendered by Express?

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, ejs, chai

I am trying to test my express web application using mocha and chai, but I am unable to figure out how to test the HTTP requests being handled by express. I am using ejs as my view engine so most of my route handlers look like this:

```
const someRouteHandlerForGETRequest = async (request, response) => {
   // usually some DB queries to get data to display in view
   const someQuery = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM table');
   var sampleData = someQuery.rows;

   response.render('ejspage', {
      user: request.session.username,
      sampleData: sampleData
   });
}
```

Because of this, I believe that my response.body is just an html file / html string (using postman I was trying to see what was in the response, it appeared to just be the html for the view)

How do I test the data being passed to the ejs file (in this example; sampleData) that is being returned from the `node-pg` database query?

My current attempt at testing is this:

```
const { assert } = require('chai');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const app = require('../index');

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/GET activeorders', () => {
  it('it should GET active orders', (done) => {
    chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
      .get('/activeorders')
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        done();
      });
  })
})
```

Basically the only this I can test is the response status, beyond that I can't figure out to test any of the values that are being returned from database queries.

I have also tried separating the model from the controller by removing the queries to the database from the route handler and instead having the route handler call a function that returns the results. This doesn't solve my problem though because using `chai-http` to test a HTTP request still doesn't give me access to the data since the route handler is simply rendering the ejs page with the data.

Comment: It seems you have to either test the HTML to see if it contains what it's supposed to or you have to mock `response.render()` where you can intercept the data itself that is passed to the template.

Comment: @jfriend00 how could I possibly go about doing this? I've changed my architecture to more closely follow the MVC architecture, so now the route handler is just calling a function that is performing a query and returning the results. Only problem is I still don't know how to intercept that data, when the http get request is triggered it is still just serving the html of the ejs file

Comment: In your first code block in your SQL statement you didn't put an ending quotation mark (`'`). May be a typo?

Comment: Wouldn't you test the controller function directly?

Comment: @code ah yes Ill fix that, that wasn't a problem in my code I was just making an example sql query